# Как правильно объявить интерфейс в Hypodermic?

Tags: c++

Пробую в проекте применить IOC контейнер [Hypodermic](https://github.com/ybainier/Hypodermic) для управления зависимостями. Подскажите, что я делаю не так? Есть код:

```
#include "Hypodermic/ContainerBuilder.h"
#include "Hypodermic/Container.h"

class A
{
    public:

        virtual void method1()abstract;
};

class B:public A
{
    public:
        void method1() override
        {
        }
};

int main()
{
    Hypodermic::ContainerBuilder builder;
    builder.registerType<B>().asSelf().as<A>().singleInstance();
    auto container = builder.build();
    container->resolve<A>()->method1();
    return 0;
}
```

Компилятор выдает ошибку **error C2259: 'A': cannot instantiate abstract class**
Хотя по документации данный код должен работать. Использую boost 1.6. Скажите, кто-нибудь использовал данную библиотеку? Если использовал подскажите, как делать правильно?

Comment: что за `abstract` после `method1`? Так нельзя в C++. Ваш код не может компилироваться

Comment: На какую строку выдает ошибку? Смущает `abstract` в классе `A`. Допускаю, что это какой-то `define`, разворачивающийся в `= 0`.

Comment: Когда исправите `abstract`(если это надо исправлять) попробуйте убрать `asSelf` из цепочки. Я не знаком с этой библиотекой, но это выглядит лишним.

Comment: abstract это define в Visual Studio 2015. Мне нужно что бы этот экземпляр этого класса был доступен и как интерфейс от которого он унаследован и как сам класс